# How I will get the active textfield in Tableview with cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, textfield

I have a tableview cell. In that I have a textfield. When I am selecting a value from picker view it is coming in every textfield. How I will get the active textfield in Tableview with cell. I have tried:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CustomCell *currentCell = (CustomCell *) textField.superview.superview;
    NSIndexPath *currentIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:currentCell.center];
    NSLog(@"%@",currentIndexPath);
}
```

Comment: Share your code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Instead of `indexPathForRowAtPoint` you can use tag to indexPath and use [cellForRowAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrowatindexpath) to get that particular cell and reload that specific row only [reloadrowsatindexpaths](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrowsatindexpaths)

Comment: are you using dynamic uitableviewcell?

Comment: This delegate method is in cell or in view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Write `textField.delegate = self` in your Cell class in awakeFromNib or cell for RowatIndexPath method. So that in cell class you implement the textField delegate method. Then You will get the particular selected textField.